# PHP syntax help for checking multiple IDS in an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am using contact form 7 in wordpress and had to create a custom hook for the form action url. I have it working if I want to check if a particular forms "id" exist, and if so to send it to another url. That code looks like this:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url');

function wpcf7_custom_form_action_url($url)
{
    global $wpcf7_contact_form;

    if ($wpcf7_contact_form->id === 333)
    {
        return 'http://mydomain.com/Leads/';
    }
    else
    {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

However, I have 4 forms that I want it to check to see if any of them exist to send the to the same url as above (where its my domain url). If I try adding multiple ids it breaks. This is what I have tried:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url');

function wpcf7_custom_form_action_url($url)
{
    global $wpcf7_contact_form;

    if ($wpcf7_contact_form->id === 333 || 334 || 335 || 336)
    {
        return 'http://mydomain.com//Leads/';
    }
    else
    {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

The code above seems to not work.

I have also tried to check it as an array like this:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url');

function wpcf7_custom_form_action_url($url)
{
    global $wpcf7_contact_form;

    if( !in_array($wpcf7_contact_form->id,array(660, 684, 685, 686)))
    {
        return 'http://mydomain.com/Leads/';
    }
    else
    {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Again, it appears that this is not correct. Can anyone see anything that is incorrect above. I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to check forms with e.g. IDs `(660, 684, 685, 686)` right?

If that is the case, you have inverted the `in_array` statement (`! in_array`)

Change:

```
if( !in_array($wpcf7_contact_form->id,array(660, 684, 685, 686)))
```

Into

```
if(in_array($wpcf7_contact_form->id,array(660, 684, 685, 686)))
```

At least, `in_array` is the best way to check for multiple values. So that should be kept in your final code!

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer for being the first to point out the inverted array. CF7 is temperamental. On the page now, it hangs and I just get a spinning cursor even though I have the redirect correctly added through contact form 7's additional settings (after the data is posted to the custom functions url). The forms will only be accessible through a mobile device, in which case my forms all send the data to the proper url now and return to the correct success page. The fact that I overlooked the inverted array though was definitely something that needed to be addressed.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
if ($wpcf7_contact_form->id === 333 || 334 || 335 || 336)
```

on:

```
if (in_array($wpcf7_contact_form->id, array(333, 334, 335, 336)))
```

Because your `if` statement is always `True`

Comment: The asker already tried in_array(), apparently to no success. What did they do wrong?

Comment: @StephenTG: I'd say the var is a string, containing wite-space?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Just saying, if you're going to suggest "Use in_array()" and they already have, say what they did wrong.

Comment: @AmazingDreams I did, and upvoted since you explained it. I'm not so much searching for why as recommending that if an answer suggests something the user is already doing, it should explain why they are doing it wrong/sub-optimally

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempted (with the `||`) is outright invalid. Check out PHP's operator precedence rules: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

The code is being parsed/executed as:

```
if (($wpcf7_contact_form->id === 333) || 334 || 335 || 336)
    ^--                             ^--
```

(note the extra brackets). The equality test is performed and returns a true/false value, which you then do a logical `OR` operation with a series of integers:

```
0 || 334 || 335 || 336  -> 0 || 351 -> 351 -> true
1 || 334 || 335 || 336  -> 1 || 351 -> 351 -> true
```

Your in_array() version is correct, except you're `!`-notting the in_array test, so you redirect if the retrieved id ISN'T one of those values. If I'm reading your question right, that's the opposite of what you want. Use `in_array()`, instead of `!in_array()`.